# in R an inconsistent behavior for prediction in nonparametric logistic regression using poly(x,i)

Tags: r, logistic-regression, polynomials

To find the best logistic model based on AIC I run a loop on the German credit data from UCI repository ([here](http://%22http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/credit-screening/crx.data)) as follows:
1) I save the data in a data frame called "credit" with headers from A1 to A16 (with A16 as the response, and only A2 and A3 as the independent variables).
2) Run the following code:

```
credit <-
read.csv("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/credit-    screening/crx.data", na.strings="?",col.names=paste0('A',1:16))

#Remove rows with <NA> 
credit <- credit[!is.na(credit$A2) & !is.na(credit$A2)&!is.na(credit$A16),]
print(head(credit))
print(tail(credit))

k<-5
pAIC<-c()
pd<-c()
library(splines)
for (i in 1:k){
  for (j in 1:k){
      if(i==1 & j==1){
        optPmodel<-pModel<-
           glm(A16 ~poly(A2,i)*poly(A3,j),family=binomial, data=credit)
        bestPAIC<-extractAIC(pModel)[2]
        pd<-c(pd,extractAIC(pModel)[1])
        pAIC<-c(pAIC,bestPAIC)
      }else{
      pModel<-
           glm(A16 ~poly(A2,i)*poly(A3,j),family=binomial, data=credit)
        if((tmp<-extractAIC(pModel)[2]) < bestPAIC){
         bestPAIC<-tmp
         optPmodel<-pModel
        }
       pd<-c(pd,extractAIC(pModel)[1])
       pAIC<-c(pAIC,tmp)
      }
     }
}

newA2<-seq(mA2<-floor(min(credit$A2)),MA2<-ceiling(max(credit$A2)),by=1)
newA3<-seq(mA3<-floor(min(credit$A3)),MA3<-ceiling(max(credit$A3)),by=1/2)

ii<-c()
jj<-c()
for (i in newA2){
   for (j in newA3){
       ii<-c(ii,i)
       jj<-c(jj,j)
   }
}

newPts<-data.frame(A2=ii, A3=jj) #add rows
# build the predictor for all the new points
####### This is where the code crashes: 
nlogitPredP<-predict(optPmodel, newPts, type="response")
```

The first double for-loop runs over i and j both in 1:k and for each builds the logistic model A16 ~ poly(A2,i)*poly(A3,j) and sets it to optPmodel if it has better AIC than the current optPmodel. When I want to use this in predict I get the following error:

```
"Error: variables ‘poly(A2, i)’, ‘poly(A3, j)’ were specified with different              types from the fit
In addition: Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 
3: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 
4: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 
5: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 
6: In Z/rep(sqrt(norm2[-1L]), each = length(x)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
7: In Z/rep(sqrt(norm2[-1L]), each = length(x)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I should mention that when I replace poly(A2,i)*poly(A3,j) with B-spline bs(A2,df=i)*bs(A3,df=j) the code works fine. Finally, when I examine optPmodel and realized that i=5, j=5, I did the following in the interactive session:

```
optPmodel1<-glm(A16~poly(A2,5)*poly(A3,5),family=binomial,data=credit)
nlogitPredP<-predict(optPmodel1, newPts, type="response")
```

Then it works just fine. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Use more whitespace, please.